# How to use the default Substrate CLI rpc-cors values without using rpc-cors=all for a Collator node and connect from Polkadot.js Apps

Tags: polkadot-js, json-rpc, cors, substrate-parachain-template

I want to be able to connect a collator node using https://polkadot.js.org/apps that is based on the substrate-parachain-template using branch 'polkadot-v0.9.18' and is being run as a parachain in **production**, but I do not want to use `--rpc-cors=all`. Instead I want to **enable origin validation** and manually add the **default** browser origins that are allowed. It mentions what values may be provided to `--rpc-cors=` in the documentation [here](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sc_cli/struct.RunCmd.html#structfield.rpc_cors).

```bash
--rpc-cors <ORIGINS>
    Specify browser Origins allowed to access the HTTP & WS RPC servers.
    
    A comma-separated list of origins (protocol://domain or special `null` value). Value of
    `all` will disable origin validation. Default is to allow localhost and
    <https://polkadot.js.org> origins. When running in --dev mode the default is to allow
    all origins.
```

In the Substrate implementation [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/polkadot-v0.9.18/client/cli/src/commands/run_cmd.rs#L406), it shows the list of browser origins that it uses by **default**, which corresponds to the what it mentions above *"Default is to allow localhost and https://polkadot.js.org origins."*.

It previously connected successfully when using just `--rpc-cors=all`. But why after I provide the options shown below instead does it give the following error in the browser console `API-WS: disconnected from wss://<MY_PARACHAIN_DOMAIN>: 1006:: Abnormal Closure` and not output the warning `Blocked connection to WebSockets server from untrusted origin: <REQUEST_ORIGIN>` (since it uses ['jsonrpc-ws-server' crate](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/polkadot-v0.9.18/client/rpc-servers/Cargo.toml#L25) to verify whether each request origin header is in the list of allowed origins) in the collator logs when I then try to connect from the https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss://<MY_PARACHAIN_DOMAIN> endpoint?

```
./target/release/parachain-collator \
--alice \
--collator \
--force-authoring \
--chain rococo-local-parachain-2000-raw.json \
--port 40333 \
--ws-port 8844 \
--rpc-cors="http://localhost:*,http://127.0.0.1:*,https://localhost:*,https://127.0.0.1:*,https://polkadot.js.org" \
--unsafe-ws-external \
--unsafe-rpc-external \
--rpc-methods=Unsafe` \
-- \
--execution wasm \
--chain ./res/rococo-raw.json \
--port 30343 \
--ws-port 9977
```

Comment: Luke, in general can I suggest you condense your questions into the specific information needed to help you. It is impossible to parse all of the content you are writing. Treat this as a question and answer forum, not a blog.

Comment: Shawn i've condensed the question now

Comment: This would be incorrect `wss://<MY_PARACHAIN_DOMAIN>` - the CORS list if for the browser you connect from, not websocket endpoint it runs on. For your disconnect, ensure it really is `wss://`, i.e. behind nginx with a cert.

Comment: If I use `--rpc-cors=all` it successfully connects from the browser when going to https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss://<MY_PARACHAIN_DOMAIN>, so I think having https://polkadot.js.org in the `--rpc-cors` comma separated list of values covers that, but I still get the same error when I remove `wss://<MY_PARACHAIN_DOMAIN>` from that list. if I instead try to connect using just ws with https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws://<MY_PARACHAIN_DOMAIN>, I get browser error `Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.`

Comment: From the apps even I've noticed that if I simply try to connect with `--rpc-cors all` it works however `--rpc-cors "http://0.0.0.0","http://localhost:*"`, etc. none of which work and it's quite strange.

Comment: @Purple_Turtle hey, have you found a solution for this --rpc-cors problem? Because I tried a long time ago to use this flag and it wasn't working when I specified the domains